# how to pipe a find with exec as an argument to a next command

Tags: bash, find

I use the following `find` command to find directory names that don't have a specific file

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/results.json" ';' -print
```

I would like to pipe those directories one at a time, such that each will be an argument to an individual command.

for example, if `dir1`, `dir2` ... are the resulting directories, then I would like to call next to

```
command -arg1 -arg2 --dir dir1
command -arg1 -arg2 --dir dir2
.
.
```

How can I do that?
I tried to use xargs with no luck:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/results.json" ';' -print | xargs python ../../my_script.py --metric abcd  --arg2 --dir {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already running one `-exec` to execute something for each directory. If you want to run a second command, just add a second `-exec`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' \
  -exec test -e "{}/results.json" ';' \
  -exec ../../my_script.py -arg1 -arg2 --dir '{}' ';'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to run multiple commands on entries from `find` then it is much more efficient to iterate results of `find` in a `while` loop like this:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
   echo "Processing directory: $dir"
   [[ -e $dir/results.json ]] || ../../my_script.py -arg1 -arg2 --dir "$dir"
done < <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)
```